# rtrim with underscore in php

Tags: php, trim

I have line as 'Delux Room_room'. I want get 'Delux Room' as result. I tried following codes.

Following code give following result.

```
echo $row.'<br/>';
echo rtrim($row, 'room') .'<br/>'; 
echo rtrim($row, '_room') .'<br/>';
```

Result ;-

```
Delux Room_room
Delux Room_
Delux R
```

But i want Delux Room. Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo rtrim($row, '_room') .'<br/>';
```

That says "remove characters from the end of the string until you get to one that isn't `_`, `r`, `o` or `m`."  Which obviously isn't what you mean.  From [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

> `$charlist` You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the charlist parameter. Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters.

You provide a list of characters, not a string you want to remove.

You should probably use [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) instead:

```
echo substr($row, 0, -5); // remove the last 5 characers
```

Another solution would be to use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) to replace unwanted substrings:

```
echo str_replace('_room', '', $row); // replace "_room" with an empty string
```

Note that this is less precise than the `substr` approach.

Answer (score 0):

[`rtrim`](http://php.net/rtrim)'s second argument is a *set* of characters. You'll have to write your own method to remove a specific string instead:

```
function rtrim_str($str, $trim) {
  if (substr($str, -strlen($trim)) == $trim) {
    return substr($str, 0, -strlen($trim));
  }
  return $str; // String not present at end
}

echo rtrim_str($row, '_room');
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to @lonesomeday's solution, if your last past is of variable length:

```
$pos = strrpos($row, '_');
echo $substr($row, 0, $pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `str_replace` instead of `rtrim`, like this:

```
echo $row.'<br/>';
echo str_replace('room', '', $row) .'<br/>'; 
echo str_replace('_room', '', $row) .'<br/>';
```